# fetch data from different tables in the same database PHP

Tags: php

So here's my  problem, I'm trying to fetch data from different tables, I already wrote the code for fetching from one table, but I couldn't fetch another data from the other table, here is my code:

```
 <?php
}
else
{
    $q = mssql_query("SELECT fdExp, fdGameMoney, fdUserNum FROM UserInfoGame WHERE fdUserNum = '".$_SESSION['fdUserNum']."'");
?>
    <div class="login2" style="color:#a1a1a1;">
    <font size="3"><div style="font-size:16px; margin-left:10px;">Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></div></font>
    <div style="font-size:14px; margin-left:15px; margin-top:5px;">
        <font size="2">TR: <?php echo mssql_result($q, 0, 'fdGameMoney'); ?>
        <div style="margin-top:-5px;">Exp: <?php echo mssql_result($q, 0, 'fdExp'); ?></div>
        <div style="margin-top:-5px;">UserNum: <?php echo mssql_result($q, 0, 'fdUserNum'); ?></div>
        <div style="margin-left:5px;">
```

the other table called `"tbl.cash"` and the rows are *"MC"* and *"usernum"*
the code should check the usernum if it's the same it gonna fetch the data of how much mc he got..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is the problem? Do you get any errors?
The following should work:

```
<?php

$q = mssql_query($conn, "SELECT mc FROM tbl.cash WHERE usernum = '".$_SESSION['fdUserNum']."'");
   if(!is_null($MC = mssql_result($q, 0, 'mc'))) {
      // do output here
      echo $MC;
   }
```

Perhaps a JOIN would do the same.

```
SELECT * FROM userinfogame
LEFT JOIN tbl.cash ON userinfogame.fdUserNum = tbl.cash.usernum;
```